# Legendre's Equation by inverse series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, laurent-series, legendre-polynomials

Find the solution of Legendre's equation
$$ (1-x^2)y'' -2xy' + l(l+1)y = 0 $$
in the form of inverse power series:
$$y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{\sigma - n} $$

*Hint*: $\sigma = l$ and $\sigma = -(l+1)$ are the solutions

I have tried substituting the series into the equation according to the Frobenius method, but it doesn't yield the right values for sigma.

*(I essentially end up with a series in $x^{\sigma - n}$ and one in $x^{\sigma - n -2}$, but due to the inverse nature of the series, after rewriting the two sums as the same power, the series previously in $x^{\sigma - n -2}$ is the one starting at a lower n. However, this series has no dependence on l, so the correct values of sigma can never be achieved by choosing n=0.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
y&=& a_0 x^{\sigma}+ a_1 x^{\sigma-1}+ a_2 x^{\sigma-2}+ \cdots \\
y'&=& \sigma a_0 x^{\sigma-1}+  (\sigma -1) a_1 x^{\sigma-2}+ (\sigma -2)a_2 x^{\sigma-3}+ \cdots \\
y''&=& \sigma (\sigma -1) a_0 x^{\sigma-2}+  (\sigma -1)(\sigma -2) a_1 x^{\sigma-3}+ (\sigma -2)(\sigma -3)a_2 x^{\sigma-4}+ \cdots \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Substitute these into $(1-x^2)y'' -2xy' + l(l+1)y = 0$
\begin{eqnarray*}
&a_0 x^{\sigma}( \color{blue}{ -\sigma (\sigma -1)-2 \sigma + l(l+1)} )  \\
&+a_1 x^{\sigma-1}( (\sigma-1) (\sigma -2)-2 (\sigma-1) + l(l+1) )  \\
&+ x^{\sigma-2}( a_2((\sigma-2) (\sigma -3)-2 (\sigma-1) + l(l+1))+ a_0 \sigma (\sigma -1) )  \cdots =0
\end{eqnarray*}
So we have $\color{blue}{ -\sigma (\sigma -1)-2 \sigma + l(l+1)}=0$.